# Java escape characters in strings - string contains \r (need to keep "r")

Tags: java

I have a string "EAD\rgonzalez" which is passed to me.
I need to pull out "rgonzalez" from it.
I am running into problems with the "\" character.
I cannot find the index of it, I cannot replace it, etc.
Any help on pulling the data after the "\" would be appreciated.
The string that i receive is in the format of domain\username; the data can vary.

Another example would be US\ngross where \n would be interpreted as a newline character.

To clarify, I am not adding a '\', i am trying to split a string on a '\'

This string contains '\r' which in itself is a character, a special one.
I need a way to make \r contained within my string two separate characters, a '\' and an 'r'.

Comment: `System.out.println("EAD\\rgonzalez".split("\\\\")[1]);`

Comment: System.out.println("EAD\rgonzalez".split("\\\\")[1]);  produces: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - 1

Comment: Because `\r` is a carriage return.

Comment: therein lies the problem :)

Comment: So, split at the `\r` and prepend a `r`?

Comment: the string can vary, it is a domain\username of users of the app.  this example is just illustrative of any problem username that could be passed, examples EAD\ngross, this would be a similar problem where \n is a newline....

Comment: If the raw string you get is `domain\user`, then splitting as \\ is correct... The *escape characters* should not be interpreted from your input

Comment: String Str = new String("EAD\rgonzalez");
       System.out.println("Return Value :" );      
       
       for (String retval: Str.split("\\")) {
          System.out.println(retval);
       }
This above split continues to fail.

Comment: For example. http://ideone.com/ADOBm5

Comment: the output of the above for me is: -1
[EAD
gonzalez]

The r is missing.

Comment: Then you are interpreting your input differently, and it needs to be escaped properly

Comment: username = "EAD\rgonzalez";  
  System.out.println(username.indexOf("\\"));
  String[] parts = username.split("\\\\");
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));

The above is it, all i have.  I am not sure where i have gone wrong.

Comment: You still don't escape the \ in your String.

Comment: \r is an escape character... If you want a *literal* backslash, it must be `EAD\\rgonzalez`. Or, if you are reading it from a Scanner, as my link shows, it'll do that for you.

Comment: yes, that is exactly my problem.  I am collecting this string from the header data from the request object in a webapp.  I dont have control of escaping the \ as your scanner does and as tkausl suggests.  The string i have is exactly what i am getting from the header data.  If i could insert a \ in the right spot i would to escape the existing \, but i cant get the index of the original \ ...

Comment: great question, i have been testing with rgonzalez, i cannot even test with EAD\qgonzalez, because \q is not a valid string.  Now i am wondering if this whole thing is blowing up before it even gets to my code on an invalid string if the user has a first initial that results in an invalid escape character sequence, and not just in my code when it happens to be a valid escape character sequence.

Answer (score 0):

> The string that i receive is in the format of domain\username... the data can vary

The data shouldn't vary if that is the input your program expects.

> where \n would be interpreted as a newline character

I'm not sure how you'd get newlines from a single line input form. If you are, then your input is invalid because it does not follow the format you're specified and are expecting. In the case where you did interpret newlines and other whitespace characters, you would either treat the whole thing as the domain, or the username, thus potentially breaking your program logic... Since you have stated the requirement of `domain\username`, and I don't think that requires you to handle any other form of input.

> I am collecting this string from the header data from the request object in a webapp.

In that case, the raw value should not contain an escape character and is actually represented as the form `"domain\\username"` as a Java string. When you print the value, the escape characters aren't shown

> I cannot find the index of it,

With the correct representation, `indexOf("\\")` will work...

> pulling the data after the "\"

Since you would have the value as `domain\\username`, you need to escape both of the backslashes within the method of `split(String pattern)` since that is a regular expression.

For example,

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    String in = "EAD\\rgonzalez";

    System.out.println(in.indexOf("\\")); // find the index of '\'
    String[] parts = in.split("\\\\");    // split on '\\'
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));

}
```

Again, the string `"EAD\rgonzalez"` is not in the form of `domain\username`, as demonstrated here

```
System.out.print("EAD\rgonzalez".matches("[A-Z]+\\[a-z]+")); // false
```

Comment: In the example EAD is the domain and rgonzalez is the username.  When i say that the data can vary, i am referring to a variety of usernames and a variety of domains. domains [EAD, US, FM, etc], usernames in the format of first initial followed by last name.  What i need from this is the part of the domain\username which represents the username: first initial followed by last name (rgonzalez, ngross, etc)

Finding the index of the \ is not working because in this example it is followed by a r, creating a single character \r whish is not found when searching for the \ itself

Comment: Again, you need to explicitly escape the backslash

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided any code, but I'm assuming what you're doing is something like this:

```
String user = request.getParameter("user"); // user = "EAD\rgonzalez"
```

If you were to declare a static string in your application, you would have to escape the backslash because it is a special character for Java strings:

```
String user = "EAD\\rgonzalez";
```

To split that string on the backslash you must escape it **twice** in the regex that you pass to the `split` method. Once because backslash is a special character for Java strings and again because backslash is a special character for regex strings. So instead of one backlash you have four. The one is escaped so then you have two, and then both of them are escaped again.

```
String[] parts = user.split("\\\\");
```

Now you have split the string:

```
System.out.println(parts[0]); // "EAD"
System.out.println(parts[1]); // "rgonzalez"
```

Answer (score 0):

The magic you need is in org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils

Here is a demo:

```
package ignoreescapeseq2;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;
/*
 * @author Charles Knell
 */
public class IgnoreEscapeSeq2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String string = "EAD\rgonzalez";  // REQUIRED INPUT STRING

        String eString = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(string);

        String [] sArray = eString.split("\\\\");

        System.out.println("domain:   " + sArray[0]);
        System.out.println("username: " + sArray[1]);        
    }    
}
```

Here is the output:

[image: Here is the output]

Although this MAY answer the question, there does still seem to be a problem
if you must define the string in java. As you said, "EAD\xgonzalez" isn't a
valid java string because \x isn't a valid escape character.  The solution above only works if the input string never has to be explictly defined, as in the demo.